# Validar comas, comillas y dos puntos en un formulario

Tags: html, regex, formularios

Quiero permitir que el usuario pueda ingresar comas, dos puntos o comillas dentro de este campo en el formulario. Pero la expresión regular que escribí no lo permite, ¿de qué otra forma lo puedo hacer? ¿O cuál es el error en mi expresión regular?

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="titulo">Título de la obra *</label>
              <input id="titulo" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú:, ]+" name="titulo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente expresion regular: `^([a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ,"':])+$`, ten cuidado con las comillas dobles dentro de la expresion regular y el atributo del html.

Hay una pagina que te puede servir para probar tus expresiones regulares es: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular incluida en la pregunta `"[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú:, ]+"` no incluye comillas. La forma de incluirlas es la siguiente `"[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú:,\" ]+"`

Ejemplo:

NOTA: Agregué un CSS para que ponga el borde del `input` de color rosa cuando su estado sea inválido.

```css
input:invalid {
  border-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="titulo">Título de la obra *</label>
  <input id="titulo" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú:,\" ]+" name="titulo" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```